# send an email to 300 addresses of a list where only the name is differnt

Tags: email, script

I have an excel workbook that has three columns:

| Name | Last Name | Email Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Schmitt | peter.schmitt@company.de |

I need to send an email with some text but with the personal Name of the individuals:

Hello [Name] [Last Name],

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Sincerely,

Management.

How would I go about this without composing 300 Emails by hand ?

We use Microsoft exchange and this is internal communication.

My idea is to parse the entries of the first two columns to two variables x and y, then save the email and send it to the corresponding row-content of column 3.

Comment: Perhaps [Mail merge using an Excel spreadsheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3) will help. Make sure to try it out with a limited group who know you are testing before doing it for real.

Comment: Or just use a system designed to do this - most mailing list SaS provide this functionality.

Comment: @davidgo if that requires doftware installation of some sort I'm out of luck that process takes forever I would need to send these emails I'm the month of February. I was thinking about an excel macro maybe, Microsoft board means at the least

Comment: @davidgo Creating a word document that performs a mail merge using an excelsheet to send emails is definitely a system designed to do this that Phil already owns. A mail merge is the way to go here.